# Constraint API template types neatly

Tags: c++, templates, c++11

I have a template API function in my class called `template<typename T> T Get(/*stuff*/);`.  My source file implements this function for a certain list of `T` types.  If the user wants to use a type that I have not implemented, then I want the result to be a *compile* error, and not a linker error.  I don't care much about the compile message yet.  Here's what I've got so far:

MyClass.h

```
#pragma once

#define API_TYPE(X) \
  template<> struct Implemented<X> : public API<X> {}

namespace MyClassAPI
{
  template<typename T> struct API
  {
    static T Get(const T&);
  };

  template<typename T> struct Implemented {};
  API_TYPE(bool);
}

class MyClass
{
  template<typename T> friend struct MyClassAPI::API;

  public:
    template<typename T> T Get(const T& t) const
    {
      return MyClassAPI::Implemented<T>::Get(t);
    }
};
```

MyClass.cpp

```
#include "MyClass.h"

namespace MyClassAPI
{
  template<typename T> T API<T>::Get(const T& t) { return t; }
  //template struct API<bool> //Why do I need this?
}
```

main.cpp

```
#include "MyClass.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <cassert>

using namespace std;

// Main File
int main() {
  MyClass c;
  cout << "Getting true: " << c.Get(true) << endl;
  return 0;
}
```

So my question is about a line in MyClass.cpp.  Why do I need to replicate the `API<bool>` explicit declaration in the source file with `template struct API<bool>;`?  Shouldn't it know to expand the template function definition from the header file's declaration when `Implemented<bool> : public API<bool>` inherits from it?

Also, is there a way to do this without declaring my accepted type list twice?

Error without the line:

```
g++ -Wfatal-errors -Werror -std=c++11 -g -O0 -Wall -c MyClass.cpp -o MyClass.o
g++ -Wfatal-errors -Werror -std=c++11 -g -O0 -Wall test.cpp MyClass.o -o test
/tmp/ccVxp4F3.o: In function `bool MyClass::Get<bool>(bool const&) const':
MyClass.h:25: undefined reference to `MyClassAPI::API<bool>::Get(bool const&)'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
make: *** [test] Error 1
```

Answer (score 2):

The problem with your template is you're defining it's members in a separate translation unit, hence they are not visible to `main.cpp`, and C++ does not support separate translation of templates.

When you use `template struct API<bool>;` you ask the compiler to **explicitly instantiate** `API<T>` for `T = bool`. However, when doing so, you should also let the other translations units know that the instantiation takes place elsewhere by having a similar directive in the header file with template declaration:

```
extern template struct API<bool>;
```

Otherwise, move the definition of `Get` to the header file or include .cpp file in the header file (not recommended) and rely on the compiler to instantiate template members for you.

As about limiting the list of viable template parameters, I suggest an approach based on template metaprogramming.
First we'll define some facility for checking whether a type belongs to a list of types, let's call it `is_in<DesiredType, ViableTypes...>`. It will accept as template parameters a type `T` to look for and a list of types `InTypes...` for search, and provide result by a static boolean member available at compile-time.
It is implemented as a simple recursive algorithm on a list, checking each element of the list against `DesiredType` until `DesiredType` is found or the end of list is met:

```
#include <type_traits>

template<typename...> struct is_in;

template<typename T, typename InType, typename... InTypes> struct is_in<T, InType, InTypes...> {
    static constexpr bool value = std::is_same_t<T, InType> ||
        is_in<T, InTypes...>::value;
}

template<typename T> struct is_in<T> {
    static constexpr bool value = false;
}
```

Now, having `is_in`, we can just use `static_assert` and explicitly specify viable types for a template:

```
template<typename T> struct API
{
    // Only allow API<bool> and API<int>
    static_assert(is_in<T, bool, int>::value, "invalid template type for API<T>");

    static T Get(const T&);
};
```

Comment: "Move the definition to the header file" I tried moving `template struct API<bool>;` to the header file before before the definition of `Implemented<bool>` but I still get the same linker error.

Comment: I suggest moving `template<typename T> T API<T>::Get(const T& t) { return t; }` to the header file, not the explicit instantiation.
The explicit instantiation belongs in a C++ file, also you generally should explicitly state in the header file that the instantiation for a specific `T` takes place in another file:
`extern template struct API<bool>;`

Comment: Hmm I would rather not because the real function does get pretty complicated and has calls to functions only defined in the implementation file.  

By the way, doesn't the `is_in` method have the same problem, where I need to list the accepted types twice (assuming I don't move `Get`'s definition)?

Comment: Then you are missing the `extern template struct API<bool>;` declaration, add it to your header file with the template to let the compiler and linker know `Get` is defined somewhere else.

Comment: To sum it up, if you're not doing the `template/extern template` stuff, you should provide every user of your type with the definition of `Get`. As of yet, you're just declaring it, but not defining. The code in `main.cpp` has no definition of `Get` and thus the linker fails to find it.

If you want to keep the definition of `Get` in a separate translation unit, and the set of types it is defined for is pretty narrow, you should have a pair of `extern template` and `template` declarations for each such type in your header and .cpp file correspondingly.

Comment: Ahh, so it is impossible to only list them once in the header file, and have the implementation file understand that it needs to expand based on those declarations?  Looks like I need to keep both lists around then; one for declaration, and another for definition.  I guess I was trying to have a template declaration implicitly tell the source file to implement it, which isn't kosher.

Answer (score 1):

You almost have it there.

You need update `MyClass.h` to provide explicit instantiations of couple of functions and implement them in `MyClass.cpp`.

In the .h file, add:

```
// Explicit instantiations
namespace MyClassAPI
{
   template<> int API<int>::Get(const int&);
   template<> double API<double>::Get(const double&);
}
```

In the .cpp file, add:

```
// Implement the explicit instantiations

namespace MyClassAPI
{
   template<> int API<int>::Get(const int& in)
   {
      // Add whatever logic that makes sense for this type.
      return 2*in;
   }

   template<> double API<double>::Get(const double& in)
   {
      // Add whatever logic that makes sense for this type.
      return 10*in;
   }
}
```

Here's a single file version of working code:

```
#define API_TYPE(X) \
  template<> struct Implemented<X> : public API<X> {}

namespace MyClassAPI
{
  template<typename T> struct Implemented;

  template<typename T> struct API
  {
    static T Get(T const&);
  };

  API_TYPE(int);
  API_TYPE(double);
}

class MyClass
{
  template<typename T> friend struct MyClassAPI::API;

  public:
    template<typename T> T Get(const T& t) const
    {
      return MyClassAPI::Implemented<T>::Get(t);
    }
};

// Explicit instantiations
namespace MyClassAPI
{
   template<> int API<int>::Get(const int&);
   template<> double API<double>::Get(const double&);
}

#include <iostream>

int main()
{
   MyClass a;

   std::cout << a.Get<int>(10) << std::endl;
   std::cout << a.Get<double>(10) << std::endl;

   // Does not work. Produces compiler error.
   // std::cout << a.Get<float>(10) << std::endl;
}


// Implement the explicit instantiations

namespace MyClassAPI
{
   template<> int API<int>::Get(const int& in)
   {
      return 2*in;
   }

   template<> double API<double>::Get(const double& in)
   {
      return 10*in;
   }
}
```

Output:

```
20
100
```

**Update**

Here'a multiple file version:

MyClass.h:

```
#pragma once

#define API_TYPE(X) \
  template<> struct Implemented<X> : public API<X> {}

namespace MyClassAPI
{
  template<typename T> struct Implemented;

  template<typename T> struct API
  {
    static T Get(T const&);
  };

  API_TYPE(int);
  API_TYPE(double);
}

class MyClass
{
  template<typename T> friend struct MyClassAPI::API;

  public:
    template<typename T> T Get(const T& t) const
    {
      return MyClassAPI::Implemented<T>::Get(t);
    }
};

// Explicit instantiations
namespace MyClassAPI
{
   template<> int API<int>::Get(const int&);
   template<> double API<double>::Get(const double&);
}
```

MyClass.cc:

```
#include "MyClass.h"

// Implement the explicit instantiations
namespace MyClassAPI
{
   template<> int API<int>::Get(const int& in)
   {
      return 2*in;
   }

   template<> double API<double>::Get(const double& in)
   {
      return 10*in;
   }
}
```

main.cc:

```
#include <iostream>
#include "MyClass.h"

int main()
{
   MyClass a;

   std::cout << a.Get<int>(10) << std::endl;
   std::cout << a.Get<double>(10) << std::endl;

   // Does not work.
   // std::cout << a.Get<float>(10) << std::endl;
}
```

It also builds successfully and produces the same result.

Comment: Single file versions don't count, because my code works if it's all in one file as well.  You have to make sure to separate the explicit instantiations to make sure that's what they are actually doing.

Comment: @Suedocode, I added the multiple file version, with the same result.

Comment: In addition, it's still listing the implemented types twice, but more verbosely.  I think nothing short of macro magic is going to do what I want.

Comment: I think you didn't mean to have `Explicit instantiations` in the header file?

Comment: @Suedocode, yes, I did. This tells the compiler that those functions are instantiated and are implemented elsewhere.

Comment: @Suedocode, you may use macro magic. However, it still needs to be used in couple of places. The first one `API_TYPE` is helpful in preventing use of the type when it is not supported. The second is helpful in allowing you to implement them in a .cc/.cpp file. You will be able to avoid the second set if `API` can provide a generic implementation also.